# SE Mobile accessibility fail

Tags: bug, status-completed, mobile-web, accessibility

The StackExchange sites that have a mobile theme seem to include the following markup in the head (I only checked stackoverflow but I'd imagine the other sites with mobile support do the same).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
```

[This is really really bad for accessibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7766870/477127).  There's nothing worse than doing a pinch to zoom in your mobile browser only for nothing to happen.  It's not merely annoying, it makes Stack Overflow basically unusable on a mobile device for vision impaired people.

I know that there's a link to the full site on the mobile version, but because the text is so small and I can't zoom it, I was unable to find it for a long time.

Please loosen up the zoom restriction.

Comment: I'm not sure this is ideal or expected, after all most mobile apps don't allow zooming (though they're occasionally still hard to read). I started a Q on UX.SE about the topic though: http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/19464/should-mobile-sites-allow-zoom

Comment: As with most accessibility issues that I and other people with vision problems run into are usually down to the assumption that everyone has perfect or near-perfect eyesight, or at least eyesight that can be corrected to near-perfect with eyewear.  This isn't always the case.

Comment: I've...never had any problem zooming. Well, zooming *in* anyway.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We'll activate the user zoom on mobile after the next production build

Comment: Thanks, I can't tell you how much I appreciate that.

Comment: This needs more thought. It now makes any entry box not fully visible when typing on the mobile site, which is an equally bad usability nightmare.

Comment: Pinch to zoom is fine, but the auto-zooming when editing is terrible.