# Zoom on editing in mobile safari

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web, mobile-safari

As of today (I believe), when entering text (ie asking a question, entering an answer, writing a comment) in mobile safari using the mobile theme, the site zooms in so that the entry area is wider than the screen. This is incredibly annoying, please make it stop.

Comment: You'll need to enter into a cage match with the poster of [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/127421/150235) - winner takes all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no clean, universal, way to achieve selective zoom disabling.

So we're stuck choosing between hurting accessibility, or having the few people the zooming annoys (it zooms to the content area so... it's not really generally harmful IMO) zoom-out manually.

We're going to error on the side of accessibility until there's a better workaround in all mobile browsers.

Comment: It _doesnt_ zoom to the content area! It zooms in further than that.

Comment: I'm slightly mollified now I realise you can pinch to zoom out - I do most of my zooming using double taps, which don't work within the text edit area, so I thought I was stuck with scrolling left to right.