# Mobile version of site "too wide" when entering text

Tags: bug, status-declined

I asked this question on the wrong meta yesterday, so am reposting here.

When browsing the mobile version of the site and entering text using Chrome for Android 4.x the site is too wide for the screen. This happens in landscape and in portrait.

Here is a screenshot of the problem.

[image: Stack Overflow Width Problem]

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127584/zoom-on-editing-in-mobile-safari

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chrome for Android has yet to have a stable release; we do not support beta browsers.

As an aside, your question was just fine on [meta.ux](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/994/mobile-version-of-this-site-too-wide-for-device). Out of curiosity: You mentioned there that you're using the HTC Desire, which never had an official ICS update. Can I assume you're using a custom built ROM?

Comment: Correct, custom ROM on the Desire, stock on the GS3. 
I have checked in the stock browser and this problem is not present.